# Order of growth for Permutation

Tags: algorithm, big-o, permutation

This is a simple program which finds all the permutations of a given string :

```
void perm( char str[], int len )
{
if ( len == 1 )
   cout << str << endl ;
else
    for ( int i=0; i<len; i++ ) {
        swap( str[len-1], str[i] ) ;
        perm( str, len-1 ) ;
        swap( str[len-1], str[i] ) ;
    }
}
```

What is the T(n) for this function ? How to calculate the Big Oh ( or Theta ) for this function ?

Comment: What does n count here? Does it count how often perm is called or how many bytes are moved or printed?

Comment: n is the length of our input. In here, length of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the length of the initial input string be N.

Let the time taken for a call of perm(str (size = N), len=i) be T(i)

```
T(1) = N
```

and

```
T(i > 1) = iT(i-1) + i
```

then the total time taken is T(N),

To calculate the closed form of this recurrence see here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188119/closed-form-for-t1-k-tx-xtx-1-x

The answer is:

```
T(N) is approximately (N + e - 1)N!
```

So as N approaches infinity the performance of the function is:

```
O((N + e - 1)N!) = O(N(N!))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've read some where that it claims it's O( n*n! ) and I'm kinda confused with the n. Do you have any explanation ?

Comment: Thanks, I'll change the code in the question so it becomes more clear.

Comment: I am sorry but how is T(1) = n... you aren't doing n couts, only 1. T(1) is obviously 1, the recurrence is more complicated than this

Comment: @yngum: I thought you were right briefly but then I realized at len==1 the str argument is still n bytes long (to its terminating null) - so I think I'm right again.

Comment: @Andrew no, what if I choose to cout "hello world", the complexity is still the same. other word, if I make str 10 time bigger and cout "hello world", the time it take to compute should scale proportionally according to the big O, not how long "hello world" is.

Comment: @yngum: The problem was that the length of the input string (N) and the len parameter (i) need to be considered seperately.  Actually the overall recurrence is a function of N, whereas the individual terms of the recurrence are functions of i. I have gone through it all with some help from math.SE and my answer should be precise now.

Comment: @Andrew just one thing. Have you considered O(n) in the equation, because of swapping or printing ?

Comment: @ArashThr: So the reason that T(1) = N, is because for a call of perm(str(size = N), 1), the function must take time proportional to N to output the string (the cout) - so the answer is O(N(N!)).  If T(1) were 1 and not N (for example it only printed the first character of the string), than the overall complexity would be O(N!).

Answer (score 2):

For loop perform n recursion, to n*T(n-1), plus O(n) since you also need to swap 2n times, so

```
T(n) = n*T(n-1)+O(n)

n = 5 for sake of my keyboard

T(n) = n*T(n-1) + n  
T(n) = n*[(n-1)*T(n-2) + (n-1)] + n  
T(n) = n*[(n-1)*[(n-2)*T(n-3) + (n-2)] + (n+1)] + n  
T(n) = n*[(n-1)*[(n-2)*[(n-3)*T(n-4) + (n-3)] + (n-2)] + (n-1)] + n  
T(n-4) = 1 ----------------------^  
Simplify 
T(n) = n*[(n-1)*[(n-2)*[(n-3) + (n-3)] + (n-2)] + (n-1)] + n  
T(n) = n*[(n-1)*[(n-2)*[2(n-3)] + (n-2)] + (n-1)] + n  
T(n) = n(n-1)(n-2)*(n-3)*2 + (n-1)(n-2) + n(n-1) + n  
T(n) = n! + O(n*n!)    <--  wrong, see comment for right answer
T(n) = O(n*n!)    <--  wrong, see comment for right answer
```

you see the pattern

Comment: You are using `T(1) = 1` yet you came out with `n*n!`.  I think this is incorrect, `T(1) = 1` and `T(x) = xT(x) + x` should be approx `T(y) = (e)y!`.  See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188119/closed-form-for-t1-k-tx-xtx-1-x  You have made two mistakes that have combined to give the right answer, but the working is wrong.

Comment: well, O(n!) if print function is complexity of 1. surprising

Comment: @ArashThr: This answer is wrong.  `(n-1)(n-2) + n(n-1) + n` is not equal to `O(n*n!)`. I realize it has become a bit confusing.  My answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

The number of possible permutations of N items is N! (factorial), and this code seems to use O(1) operations per permutation it outputs. The cost of construction is therefore O(N!), which is equivalent to O(N^N).

Or maybe O(N!*N) since for every permutation N items are printed out to the console.

Comment: One should note that `O(N!) = O(N^N)`

Comment: I was looking for a more official solution. This one is somehow heuristic .

Comment: @ArashThr are you looking for a formal proof?

Comment: @Qnan yeah, As I said, I was looking for T(n).

Comment: Actually, that's even easier. `T(1)` takes `n` steps to output the sequence, and for any `k`, `T(k)` takes `len*(2+T(k-1))` steps.